# Echo Data From Collection to Blade View

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-blade, guzzle

I am simply (for my own testing purposes) trying to take data from a collection and pass it to a view. I am using Laravel.

I am getting my data from the GitHub API, converting it and putting it in a collection. From here it's passed to a view, but I can't output each individual field.

Here's some code:

```
$httpClient = new Client();

$response = $httpClient->get('https://api.github.com/users/<randomuser>');

$json = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

$collection = collect($json);

return view('github')->with('github', $collection);
```

and my Blade file is

```
@foreach ($github as $git)
  {{ $git }}
@endforeach
```

Now I thought it would be something as simple as `{{ $git->email }}` to output it, but I don't think the array keys are been sent (?)

Can anybody point me in the right direction of where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

-Chris

Comment: What is the results of dd($git) (in blade) of this variable?

Comment: The output of that is just `"cjmellor"` - which is my GH username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use get() method in your blade

```
$github->get('login')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. Didn't know you could use things like `get()` in Blade.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a key => val array, you should loop it as such...

```
@foreach ($github as $key => $val)
    Key: {{ $key }}  ~~ Value: {{ $val}} <br />
@endforeach
```

However if you are looking to just grab the email, use the `Collection`'s get method.

```
$email = $github->get('email')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
in your controller `use View` and in function

`$data['github_data'] = $collection;
 return view('github', $data);`

and in blade

`{{ dd($github_data) }}`

Comment: No sorry, this didn't work. I get `Undefined variable: github_data`. As the collection is basically an array, I'm unsure why I can't loop over each value.

Comment: Just check your `config/app.php` file and see if `'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,` is register under aliases section. and are you getting the data in controller and can you loop it over there?

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with Laravel try to check if you have the correct structure before trying to manipulate it.

In this case, check that:

- You are getting what you expect in $response after call *[$httpClient->get](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html)* (if you are using Guzzle).
- You have a $json with the structure that you expect to receive.
- You have a Collection instance after calling *[collect()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-collect)*.

You can use [dd()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-dd) or [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php) to see what data structure you have. What´s probably happening is that you don´t have the structure that you think.